# Matching text with xpath?

Tags: xpath, lxml

I'm screen-scraping an HTML page which contains:

```
<table border=1 class="searchresult" cellpadding=2> 
<tr><th colspan=2>Last search</th></tr> 
<tr><th align=left>Search term</th><td>xxxxxx</td></tr> 
<tr><th align=left>Result</th><td>yyyyyyyy/td></tr> 
</table>
```

I want to write an XPATH expression which gets me the data cell containing "yyyyyyyy".  I've gotten as far as

```
.//table[@class='searchresult']//tr/th
```

which gets me a list of all the table-header nodes in the table.  I can iterate over them in user code, find the one whose .text is "Results" and then call .getnext() on that to get the table-data.  But, is there a cleaner way to do this by writing a more specific XPATH pattern?  It seems like there should be, but I haven't gotten my head that far around XPATH yet to figure out how.

If it matters, I'm doing this in Python with lxml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.//table[@class='searchresult']//tr/td[preceding-sibling::th] might give you what you need.

Two comprehensive papers on semi-automatically creating XPath statements like this one, specifically for screen scraping purposes can be found here:

http://tobiasanton.com/Tobias_Anton/Academia.html

Comment: more probably, the XPath statement you're looking for might be: .//table[@class='searchresult']//tr/td[preceding-sibling::node[1] = "Result"]

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
//table/tr[last()]/td
```

This selects any `td` element that is a child of any `tr` that is the last `tr` child of any `table` in this XHTML document.

This may select more than one `td` element, depending on whether or not there is only one `table` in the XHTML document. **You need to make this expression more precise, if more than one `table` element is present**.

**For example, if the `table` in question is the first in the document, use**:

```
(//table)[1]/tr[last()]/td
```